# Moment Timezone Conversion not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

My moment object will not convert timezone. I'm trying to convert date and time object to UTC, but it just returns the original date/time with no change. Does anyone know why this is happening? It looks like it might be assuming the original time as UTC even though its not according to _d?

```
momentPre = moment(post.date + " " + post.time + "00", "YYYY-M-D HH:mm:ss")
momentAft = momentPre.toISOString()
momentParse = moment.tz(momentAft, 'America/Denver')
post.utcDate = momentParse.clone().tz("UTC")._i.substring(0,10)
```

momentParse object output (_isUTC returning true, even though its not. I have forced this to false before to test and doesnt fix the issue):

```
{ [Number: 1506010200000]
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: '2017-09-21T16:10:00.000Z',
  _f: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ',
  _tzm: 0,
  _isUTC: true,
  _pf: 
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [],
     overflow: -1,
     charsLeftOver: 0,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: true },
  _locale: Locale { ordinal: [Function], _abbr: 'en' },
  _a: [ 2017, 8, 21, 16, 10, 0, 0 ],
  _d: Thu Sep 21 2017 04:10:00 GMT-0600 (MDT),
  _z: 
   { name: 'America/Denver',
     abbrs
     ...
```

Output from momentParse.clone().tz("UTC")

```
{ [Number: 1506010200000]
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: '2017-09-21T16:10:00.000Z',
  _f: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ',
  _tzm: 0,
  _isUTC: true,
  _offset: 0,
  _pf: 
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [],
     overflow: -1,
     charsLeftOver: 0,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: true },
  _locale: Locale { ordinal: [Function], _abbr: 'en' },
  _z: 
   { name: 'UTC',
     abbrs: [ 'UTC' ],
     untils: [ Infinity ],
     offsets: [ 0 ] },
  _a: [ 2017, 8, 21, 16, 10, 0, 0 ],
  _d: Thu Sep 21 2017 10:10:00 GMT-0600 (MDT) }
```

Comment: Did you add the moment time zone js file

Comment: Yes, I am using the mrt:moment-timezone package.

Comment: I am not exactly sure from your question what exactly you want to achieve in terms of usecase and why would you need that. When you save any field in Meteor Collection, it is saved as UTC by default. The difference is felt on client side. The Client as per their timezone will be able to read the date correctly. So, why would you need timezone conversion? If you really need it can you please explain why in the question?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should show how do you call, what do you expect and what do you get. Otherwise, it's really hard to understand what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

It's working, you just get the date wrong way.

Rather than `momentObj._i.substring(0,10)` you should use `momentObj.format()` method.

```
const now = moment()
now.tz('UTC').format()
# 2017-09-22T04:39:58Z
now.clone().tz('Europe/Kiev').format()
# 2017-09-22T07:39:58+03:00
now.clone().tz('America/Denver').format()
# 2017-09-21T22:39:58-06:00
```

Here is [`.format()` documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

**Added**: using `.clone()` is needed only if you want to leave `now` unchanged, otherwise you can just do `now.tz(...).format(...)`.